# Android inconsistant animation on different devices

Tags: android, animation, device, android-animation

The app I'm building has a simple image button animation (rotate) before starting the next activity. I have tested it on the emulator and 5 different devices:

- Samsung GT-I5500

  Samsung Galaxy Nexus

  Samsung Galaxy s2

  Motorola Razr Maxx

  HTC (I don't remember the model)

The animation worked fine on all of the models, except for the Nexus. On the Nexus, the device waits the duration of the animation (500ms) before starting the next activity, so instead of the animation - just an annoying (and seemingly inexplicable to the user) delay. All of the devices were running Jelly Bean except for the GT-I5500.

Questions:

1) Why would the animation work on some devices and not others, even running the same version OS?

2) Is there a way to check if the device is 'receptive' to the animation? (I had initially thought it had something to do with the SDK version, but it doesn't)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Audio, Video, GPU acceleration are hardware dependent. You can live in the trap of Java is platform independent and there are interfaces and inheritance. 
In reality there is a Market:

- each of manufacturer want something special to him to get new Customers Money
- there are programs made by programs, those can have bugs, and if it can cave => it has, because none of testing is 100% cases.

Comment: I understand this, but wouldn't it be safe to assume that at least the Samsung s2 and the Samsung Nexus, running the same OS, would interpret animations in the same fashion?

Comment: @LMVogel Those two "Samsung" phones are very different, one is Samsung's and the other is **built** by Samsung but it is a Google device. The OS on each is going to be quite different because on a non Nexus device the manufacturer will modify Android to make their phone different as matheszabi said - often a carrier will too. A good example of this is Samsungs's in some countries only just got JellyBean but the Nexus devices have had it for months because Samsung was modding it. It may be different with your emulators depending how accurate they are but this is the case with real devices

Comment: All that said, is there a way to know how a device will behave? And if it will not 'accept' the animation, to bypass it? As I said in my question, the device that doesn't perform the animation just seems stuck, until it progresses to the next activity.

Comment: I think you can't know, because: Theoretically it is platform independent and is running. Practically is possible if: you will try on each all of the existing phones ( over 10k types) - or just the most often used, or just what you have device access, testing  possibilityes- build and internal database and check at runtime in your database will the phone really run as expected or not.